# not able to include league spartan family in my wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I want to include league spartan family in to my website.
When I use the following code, I am able to see the font family changes. But others are not able to see that.

```html
<style>@font-face {font-family: 'League Spartan';font-weight: bold;src: url("leaguespartan-bold.otf") format("opentype");}</style>
```

Comment: Be careful with **url** , there is a problem, I am sure. Generally, check that path.

Comment: @Dhara, is this style added in the body of the page or a CSS file?

Comment: inside <head></head> tag

Answer (score 0):

From my experiences, your mistake is inside **url**, please check your path. 
If you need help, please share here what is inside your theme folder.

Comment: if path is not correct, why am I seeing the font family changes in my browser. Some of my friends can see the font family change, but some doesnt